# Bachelier model: number of stocks in replicating strategy

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus

Given:

Consider a two-asset, continuous time model (B,S) where 
\begin{equation}
dB_t = B_t r dt, \quad dS_t =  \mu dt + \sigma dW_t.
\end{equation}
The question is:

1. Show that there exists a trading strategy which replicates the payout of a European call with strike K and maturity T.
2. Show that the number of shares of stock in the replicating portfolio is always non-negative but never greater than one.

Comment: this is the Bachelier model. Not the BS model since that requires drift and volatility to have an S_t coefficient.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without information on the claim to be replicated. What are the properties of the (I assume European) claim function?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to state this: The claim is a European call with strike $K$ and maturity $T$. Actually, I don't even know why a replicating strategy even exists, since I am only taught about the Black-Scholes Model in lectures.

Comment: Please edit the question and include all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1:

Show that there exists a trading strategy which replicates a European Call.

Proof:  I am actually going to prove a stronger statement: that there exists an admissible trading strategy which replicates any payoff in this market.  By the First Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing, there is no arbitrage if there exists a change of measure such that, for all assets, the following holds:
$$X_t=\mathbb{\tilde{E}}[e^{-r(T-t)} X_T | \mathcal{F}_t]$$
By Girsonav's theorem, the following change of measure can be made: 
$$d\tilde{W}_t=dW_t+\frac{\mu-rS}{\sigma}dt$$
Substituting this into the dynamics of $$dS_t=\mu dt+\sigma dW_t$$
yields
$$dS_t=rS_tdt+\sigma d\tilde{W}_t $$
The expected value of this process is
$$\mathbb{\tilde{E}}[S_T | \mathcal{F}_t]=S_t+\mathbb{\tilde{E}}\left[\int_t ^ T rS_u du |\mathcal{F}_t\right] $$
Taking the expectation inside the integral on the right hand side,
$$\mathbb{\tilde{E}}[S_T | \mathcal{F}_t]=S_t+\int_t ^ T r\mathbb{\tilde{E}}\left[S_u |\mathcal{F}_t\right] du  $$
Letting $$f(t, T)=\mathbb{\tilde{E}}[S_T | \mathcal{F}_t]$$
And taking the differential of both sides, 
$$df=rfdt \implies \frac{df}{dt}=rf$$
This is an ODE with initial condition $$f(t, t)=S_t $$
This ODE has the unique solution $$S_t e^{r(T-t)} $$
Thus $$\mathbb{\tilde{E}} [S_T e^{-r(T-t)}]=S_t e^{r(T-t)} e^{-r(T-t)}=S_t $$
Hence this model does not admit arbitrage.  By the Second Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing, there exists a unique change of measure if and only if every payoff can be replicated.  In this model with a single Brownian motion, the change of measure is one such that 
$$ dS=rS dt+\sigma(dW+\theta dt)=\mu dt+\sigma dW $$
Solving for theta, 
$$  rS+\theta \sigma=  \mu $$

Clearly this has a single solution, namely
$$\theta=\frac{\mu-rS}{\sigma} $$

This proves 1.

Part 2:  Show that the Delta of the option is between zero and one.

By Feynman-Kac and Ito's lemma,
$$e^{-rt} g(S_t, t, T)=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}[h(S_T)|\mathcal{F}_t]$$ 
implies that g has the following dynamics:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} dt+\frac{\partial g}{\partial S} dS_t+\frac{\partial^2 g}{2\partial S^2} \sigma^2 dt -rg dt $$
Comparing this with the dynamics of the self-financing replicating portfolio $$X_t=\Delta S_t+\Gamma B_t $$
$$dX_t=\Delta dS_t+\Gamma dB_t $$
By the First Fundamental Theorem of Asset pricing, $$X_t=g(S_t, t, T) $$
It is thus clear that $$\Delta=\frac{\partial g}{\partial S}$$

Writing the expectation of the payoff as an integral,
$$X_t=e^{-r(T-t)}\int_K ^ \infty (S_T-K) d\mathbb{\tilde{P}} $$
$$=e^{-r(T-t)}\int_{K-S} ^ \infty (S e^{r(T-t)} +y-K) p(y) dy $$
Taking the derivative with respect to S,
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial S}= \int_{K-Se^{r(T-t)}} ^ \infty  p(y) dy -e^{-r(T-t)}(K-Se^{r(T-t)}+Se^{r(T-t)}-K)p(y)=\mathbb{\tilde{P}}(S_T>K) $$
Thus the delta of the option can be written as a probability, which is always between zero and one.

This proves 2.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify the ODE and to remove all the integrals of r.

Comment: I've edited for clarity around the uniqueness of the change of measure and added a proof for part 2.

Comment: Thanks for your editing. But how do you get $dS= rS dt+ \sigma (dW+ \theta dt)$? Also, could you give me a source that contains more examples of the use of the second fundamental theorem of asset pricing? (I have only come across the first fund. thm. in lectures.)

Comment: Shouldn't the PDE be $ \frac{ \partial g}{\partial t} + \mu \frac{\partial g}{\partial s} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{{\partial}^2 g}{\partial s^2} = rg$ ? The $\mu$ term seems to be missing. Also, applying Ito's lemma, I get $dg(t,S_t)= (rg-\frac{\partial g}{\partial s} \mu)dt+\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial s} dS_t,$ i.e. $\Gamma = \frac{rg-\frac{\partial g}{\partial s} \mu}{r B_t}$, $\Delta= \frac{\partial g}{\partial s}$. However, it doesn't satisfy the first equation $X_t = \Delta S_t + \Gamma B_t$. Do you also get the same results for values of gamma and delta?

Comment: The PDE is done under the risk neutral measure, so $\mu $ will be missing as it doesn't enter the risk neutral stock dynamics.  

The following paper has a statement of the 2nd fundamental theorem of asset pricing: http://www.fm.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/download/publications/biagini_2010_encquantfin.pdf

The equation $X_t=\Delta S_t +\Gamma B_t$ is simply the market value of a portfolio of stocks and bonds.  The self financing property states that $dX_t=\Delta dS_t+\Gamma dB_t$.  Substituting, $dX_t=\Delta dS_t+r(X_t-\Delta S_t)dt$.  It follows that the discounted $X_t$ is a martingale.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that pdf file. But you still haven't justified why for any change of measure, we have the identity $dS_t = rS_t dt + \sigma ( dW_t + \theta dt)$. After all, $\tilde{W_t}$ is a Q-Brownian motion by Girsanov's theorem for some equivalent measure Q. But I don''t know why are you assuming that for any equivalent measure $\tilde{P}$, its Brownian motions are all of this form.

Comment: By no arbitrage, under the risk neutral measure, $dS=rSdt+\sigma d\tilde{W}_t $.  By Girsonav's theorem, $d\tilde{W}_t=dW_t+\theta dt $.  We are given $dS=\mu dt+\sigma dW_t $.  There is only one $\theta$ that converts $\mu dt+\sigma (d\tilde{W}_t-\theta dt) $ into $rSdt+\sigma d\tilde{W}_t $.

Answer (score 0):

The stock weight $\pi_t\geq0$ is nonnegative as $C_T=\max(S_T-K,0)$ is increasing in $S_T$ (always long).

$\pi_t\leq 1$ cannot be greater than one, because one can receive at most 1 stock from the call at maturity, so you dont pay more than 1 stock price for it. Otherwise, one could buy the (cheaper) call and sell the replicating portfolio for riskfree profit at maturity.